# How to calculate totals from Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a method for calculating the weights from a given dataset. The method that I'm using is written like so:

```
def wmc(classAttribute,attribute,training_set):
    attributeCount = training_set[training_set[classAttribute] == attribute].count()[classAttribute]
    total          = training_set[classAttribute].count()[classAttribute]
    print(f'{attributeCount}/{total}')
    return attributeCount/total
```

The expected values for `attributeCount` and `total` are supposed to be the total number of records with equivalent to `attribute` and the total number of records for the given dataset.

However, these comeback as non-numeric types. How can I get the count of records from the dataset where `value == attribute`?

Comment: t is very difficult to answer your question without seeing both the data and the code that you have written that produces your problem. Please read about how to ask a good question and try to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it.

```
def wmc(classAttribute,attribute,training_set):
    attributeCount = len(training_set[training_set[classAttribute] == attribute].index)
    total          = len(training_set[classAttribute].index)
    print(f'{attributeCount}/{total}')
    return attributeCount/total
```